# Why GitHub makes me resolve conflicts that are actually additions?

Tags: git, github

I'm working on some project and I just created a repo and made initial commit. Then I edited eslint config (added new rule), created PR to merge it in master but GitHub wants me to resolve this "conflict".

[image]

Why is it even a conflict? It's just a simple addition which doesn't have to be resolved manually at all. Did I miss something in repository configuration?

Comment: FYI this has nothing to do with GitHub, it's your local copy of GIT that does this

Comment: That's on GitHub.com, it's not on my local machine.

Comment: Without more context, I could imagine that the head of `master` *deleted* a line that `development` *changed*, and so Git needs you to choose between the two alternatives.

Comment: For the benefit of this question, could you reproduce this issue with a public repo that you could provide us the link to?

Comment: To see the actual conflict, set `merge.conflictStyle` to `diff3`.